# How to move up view after presenting view?

Tags: ios, swift, view, keyboard, presentviewcontroller

I have a view that have a textfield in it. And whenever user tap on that texfield a keyboard show up then I move up the view a little bit. Everything was fine until I present a new viewcontroller then dismiss it, after I dismiss the new viewcontroller i got a  weird behavior on my old viewcontroller, some thing like this:

[image]

it's like bouncing a bit before I show my keyboard after dismiss the new viewcontroller and this will affect when i hide keyboard too,my view become lower than it's original position:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 100

}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

    self.view.frame.origin.y += 100
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this, you can't always assume the keyboard will be that height, especially with the advent of third party keyboards.

In your `keyboardWillHide` and `keyboardWillShow` you need to get the keyboard height as so:

```
if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize
}
```

Comment: i think that is not the problem, i've tried that and still got the same problem after dismiss my newviewcontroller